# Combining RR/OR

Tags: meta-analysis, odds-ratio, relative-risk, systematic-review

I am doing meta analysis for my thesis and I have a problem with my data. I want to investigate whether psychiatric comorbidity have effect on increasing risk to my outcome. I got 3 studies that talked about it and they used OR/RR analysis to show the association between comorbidity and outcome. However, 2 of the studies reported the comorbidity by the psychiatric disorder types (ex: ADHD, Personality Disorder) and the other study only reported the comorbidity in general. So, is there any way to combine the RR/OR number of psychiatric disorder types so I can get RR/OR number of psychiatric comorbidity in general?